# Cross Browser Cookie Expiration Inconsistencies

Tags: php, browser, cookies, cross-browser

I'm looking for a way to set cookies with a short duration against all browsers. Apparently each browser handles the PHP setcookie method differently. Below are my results.

**The PHP code:**

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+7200, "/", ".domain.com", 1, true);
```

**The Results:**

*OPERA 11.10*

```
Local time of test: 1316621628
PHP Server Time: Wed Sep 21 07:58:35 PDT 2011
Cookie Expiration Time: 2011-09-21 - 20:58:35
```

*Chrome 6.0.472.63*

```
Local time of test - 1316621761
PHP Server Time - Wed Sep 21 08:01:21 PDT 2011
Cookie Expiration Time - Wednesday, September 21, 2011 9:01:21 PM
```

*Firefox 4*

```
Local time of test: 1316622064
PHP Server Time: Wed Sep 21 08:07:38 PDT 2011
CookieExpiration Time: Wednesday, September 21, 2011 10:22:50 PM
```

*Safari 3.2.3*

```
Local time of test: 1316622359
PHP Server Time: Wed Sep 21 08:10:48 PDT 2011
CookieExpiration Time: 9/21/11 5:10 PM
```

*Internet Explorer 8*

```
Local time of test: 1316623009
PHP Server Time: Wed Sep 21 08:21:37 PDT 2011

Cookie Data: 
TestCookie
x
domain.com/
9728
3932016640
30177410
2837190416
30177404
```

As you can see, the expiration date/time for the cookies varies widely from working as intended to being several hours in the past to only being 1 hour! Very frustrating.

In addition to trying the above method, I've also tried setting the exact expiration date/time via unixtime... I've done this with both time() at the PHP level, or utilizing the browser's unixtime retrieved through JavaScript.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, 1316621928, "/", ".domain.com", 1, true);
```

Each browser handles this differently as well. I can't seem to find one method that works the same for all browsers. Is anyone aware of a method that accomplishes this?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you try a longer duration. like a day/week/year?

Comment: Still inconsistent, but, when you set an expiration for 2/3 weeks from now you don't mind if its off a few hours. However, with this current requirement, they must all be synced to the minute.

Comment: Can you show your results for `setcookie("TestCookie", $value, 1316621928, "/", ".domain.com", 1, true);`? And results when you do the same using javascript.

Comment: Can you try setting your server's time in UTC while making sure it's the correct time, and also make sure that your desktop's local time is set correctly?

Comment: Was there any resolution?  I'm running into some strange cookie expiration issues myself.